# Problem with nullable types in .NET WS client

Tags: c#, java, .net

I've WebService written in Java that has method

```
@WebMethod    
public void createUser(Long id, String name)
{

}
```

Now I want to use this method in .NET client. I think I should be able to use this method with nullable long but I can't. Is there any annotation or maybe some other way to force .NET use nullable types?

I think that if in java I use Long (not long) so it's natural that in .NET  I'll have method with nullable parameter

Answer (score 1):

In C#, nullable types use the '?' markup, so the datatype would be `long?`, or `Nullable<Long>`.  If you need to get the actual long out of them, the best way to do it is `NullableLong.Value`

Thanks to Gratz' comment!  What he means is, in a nullable type, you want to do `NullableLong.HasValue`, which returns a bool saying whether or not the variable is null.

Comment: You also might want to check .HasValue first